# Orthogonal Matrices and Similarity Transforms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Sorry I can't be more specific with the title. I really don't know what to call this and about 2 hours of Googling has yielded no results.

All we are given:

- $U$ is $n\times n$ and orthogonal
- $Ax = y$ for some nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix $A$
- $B = U^T AU$
- $Bu = v$

How are $u$ and $v$ related to $x$ and $y$?

What I want to know is if $A = U BU^T$. I feel like there's not enough information given to solve the problem. The first thing that came to mind was a similarity transform, but there's nowhere near enough information about $A$. I'm really lost at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, $U^{-1} = U^T$.  So if $B = U^T A U$, then
$U B U^T = U U^T A U U^T = A$.  On the other hand, $U^T B U = (U^T)^2 A U^2$, which is not the same as $A$ unless $U^2$ happens to commute with $A$.

Comment: Okay. My linear algebra is very rusty. I forgot you could multiply out of order (if that makes sense). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We can rephrase $Bu = v$ as
$$
U^T A U u = v \implies A(Uu) = A(Uv)
$$
So, we have $A(Uu) = A(Uv)$ and $Ax = Ay$.  So, $Uu$ and $Uv$ satisfy the same equation as $x$ and $y$.

The most concise way we can phrase this is to say that $x - y$ and $U(u-v)$ are both in the nullspace of $A$.  We don't know anything outside of this from the information provided.

Comment: Thanks! I was really overthinking the problem. It's a lot more simple than expected!